# Send url to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am pretty new to python, but like it.
I have a problem.
I wish to parse a url to my function KB, from my button in tkinter, so when user click on skanderborg it take and url and parse this to the url in my function, but i can't get it work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def kb():
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    seven_day = soup.find(class_="today_nowcard-container")
    forecast_items = seven_day.find_all(class_="today_nowcard-main")
    details_items = seven_day.find(class_="today_nowcard-section")
    place = seven_day.find(class_="today_nowcard-location").get_text()
    daily_temp = seven_day.find(class_="today_nowcard-temp").get_text()
    cloud = seven_day.find(class_="today_nowcard-phrase").get_text()
    print(place)
    print(daily_temp)
    print(cloud)
    data = ("place" + "cloud")
    return place, cloud, daily_temp

var2 = kb()
top = tkinter.Tk()
placevar1 = StringVar()
placevar1.set(var2)
label = Label(top, textvariable=placevar1 )
B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Copenhagen", command = kb)
B2 = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Skanderborg", command=lambda: kb(url ="https://weather.com/weather/today/l/ad60b9f8e5bf7d9baa35aefb5e724782692ad6b7a35f43ee43caa4182838eef7"))
label.pack()
B.pack()
B2.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is not properly formatted: your return is outside of the function; you have undefined variable `url` inside of the function — Python can't guess you want to pass url, so you need to change definition of your function to `def kb(url):`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your kb function is not expecting any parameters.

Where you have

```
def kb():
```

You might need to put

```
def kb(url) :
```

instead. This will make your kb function take the URL you are calling it with, and use it throughout the function as variable name url.

Answer (score 0):

Two or three things were off.

Don't forget the arguments in your functions as @tomh1012 pointed out.
 And if you want to update your text then `kb` must take two arguments.
Becomes:

```
def kb(url, text_widget):
```

Be careful about indentation they were one or two missing (I don't know if it is a bad copy/paste)

Don't forget the keyword `lambda:`  if you want to use your command to be a lambda expression. (you forgot it in the first `B` button)

Also a piece of advise don't hesitate to use a python IDE it simplifies a lot of debugging and syntax problem (ex: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

**Full working example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def kb(url, text_widget):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    seven_day = soup.find(class_="today_nowcard-container")
    forecast_items = seven_day.find_all(class_="today_nowcard-main")
    details_items = seven_day.find(class_="today_nowcard-section")
    place = seven_day.find(class_="today_nowcard-location").get_text()
    daily_temp = seven_day.find(class_="today_nowcard-temp").get_text()
    cloud = seven_day.find(class_="today_nowcard-phrase").get_text()
    print(place)
    print(daily_temp)
    print(cloud)
    data = ("place" + "cloud")
    text_widget.set((place, cloud, daily_temp))
    return place, cloud, daily_temp


top = tkinter.Tk()
placevar1 = StringVar()
var2 = kb(url =
"https://weather.com/weather/today/l/ad60b9f8e5bf7d9baa35aefb5e724782692ad6b7a35f43ee43caa4182838eef7", text_widget=placevar1)
label = Label(top, textvariable=placevar1 )
B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Copenhagen", command = lambda: kb(url="https://weather.com/weather/today/l/DAXX0009:1:DA", text_widget=placevar1))
B2 = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Skanderborg", command= lambda: kb(url =
"https://weather.com/weather/today/l/ad60b9f8e5bf7d9baa35aefb5e724782692ad6b7a35f43ee43caa4182838eef7", text_widget=placevar1))

label.pack()
B.pack()
B2.pack()
top.mainloop()
```